# Вопрос из любознательности по JS

Tags: javascript

Господа.

Я вняла вашим насмешкам и решила разобраться в вопросе создания и использования JavaScript, начала читать соответствующую литературу, и тут в голове случился диссонанс. В книге сэр Фланиган пишет, что скрипт нужно подключать по ссылочке, как положено, и его внедрение на страницу весьма некорректно, но чтобы узнать глубже, нужно еще n-ное количество страниц перелопатить, и, чтобы не ломать мозг, спешу спросить у вас, как у знающих и практикующих. На вопрос "а погуглить, не?" отвечу сразу - я не доверяю, там может быть написано что угодно, и нет им веры, а точных и верных источников, таких как вы, я не знаю более.

Итак, мой знакомы программист взял скрипт и пихнул его в виджет, находящийся в хэдэре. Да, работает, да, жестко анимирует, но работает.
Фланиган сказал, нужно подключать через хэд ссылочкой.
А программиста учили 5 лет.
Вопрос: кто прав и в чем нюансы?

Comment: А правильный вопрос, кстати.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Nik555](/users/18876/nik555)](/users/18876/nik555) написал всё верно. Но стоит зайти ещё и с другой плоскости.

Сэр Фланиган - это человек, который написал книгу по JS, он знает, сколько трудностей создаёт нагромождение скриптов во вьюхах, поэтому он изначально будет делать и советовать делать отдельный файл со своими скриптами для каждой страницы.

В настоящее время при разработке любого проекта, будь то сайт-визитка или крупный портал, стараются сделать красивый и хороший фронтенд и подключают различные библиотеки и плагины для этого, всё это приводит к тому, что и свой JS это далеко не 2 строчки.

Исходя из написанного выше, я бы всё-таки доверился сэру Фланигану и сразу создавал отдельный файл для JS, а ваш знакомый программист просто ленив в плане фронтенда, как и многие программисты.

P.S. Для тех, кто считает, что новая ссылка это лишний запрос, отвечу сразу: минимизация, обфускация и склеивание JS вам в помощь.

Answer (score 5):

Если кода JS много, то лучше его подгружать отдельным файлом, если же требуется написать всего лишь пару строк JS, то можно обойтись без файла, а просто написать его между тегами `<script>`.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, правильной практикой считается подключение скрипта в конце документа, а не в хедере.